# What is the return value of subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, linux

I am not sure what the return value of `subprocess.call()` means.

- Can I safely assume a zero value will always mean that the command executed successfully?
- Is the return value equivalent to the exit staus of a shell command?

For example, will the following piece of code work for virtually any command on Linux?

```
 cmd = "foo.txt > bar.txt"
 ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
 if ret != 0:
     if ret < 0:
         print "Killed by signal", -ret
     else:
         print "Command failed with return code", ret
 else:
     print "SUCCESS!!"
```

Please enlighten me :-)

Answer (score 39):

Yes, `Subprocess.call` returns "actual process return code".

You can check official documentation of [Subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and [Subprocess.Popen.returncode](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode)

Comment: I'm getting `returncode=52`. Cannot find what that means anywhere.

Comment: @NicScozzaro, have you tried the subprocess.getstatusoutput() function?

Answer (score 15):

It is the return code, but keep in mind it's up to the author of the subprocess what the return code means.  There is a strong culture of 0 meaning success, but there's nothing enforcing it.

Answer (score 6):

You are at the mercy of the commands that you call. 
Consider this:

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
success=False
if not success:
    exit()
```

Then running your code (with cmd='test.py') will result in 
SUCCESS!!

merely because test.py does not conform to the convention of returning a non-zero value when it is not successful.