# Get exit code of a command

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

For example, I have a command commandA and want to get the the exit code after commandA is executed. CommandA is expected to be failed, so the exit code we should get is 1.

If I type command in the terminal as `commandA;echo $?`, a 1 get displayed on the screen. However, when I do it with python, things went wrong.

I have tried to call commandA with `os.system(commandA)` or `subprocess.call(commandA.split())`, and then call `os.popen('echo $?').read()`, results are 0.

`os.popen('commandA;echo $?').read()` gives me a correct result but the process of commandA is not displayed in the screen, which is what I don't want it happens.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696998/what-is-the-return-value-of-subprocess-call

Comment: Are you running Python scripts in-line on command line? The shell interpreter will expand $? early, before passing the string to Python.  `$ python -c "import os; os.system('echo test; false; echo $?')"
test
0`
`$ python -c "import os; os.system('echo test; false; echo \$?')"
test
1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`subprocess.call` returns the exit code directly:

```
exit_code = subprocess.call(commandA.split())
```

The reason your attempts with `echo $?` are not working is that both `echo` (typically) and `$?` (certainly) are constructs of the shell, and don't exist in Python.

Comment: oh! Thanks a lot! it works. So what python does is not just copying the exactly same command to the terminal and call it?

Comment: It depends. If you pass a string (just `commandA`) and set `shell=True`, then Python sends it to the shell (typically bash). But then you also have the usual shell troubles with quoting, whitespace, escaping, etc., so in general this is not recommended. If, on the other hand, you pass the command as a list (`commandA.split()`), Python doesn't use the shell and goes directly to the kernel. (The _terminal_ is just the program that shows the input/output of programs on your screen, and doesn't enter the picture here.)

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on python version. You can do:

```
result=subprocess.check_output(['commandA'],Shell='True')
```

For 3.x you do:

```
result = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or you can do with a try catch to see only errors. Something like:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["command"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    errorCode = e.returncode
```